# Trouble Mounting (Intel) RAID in Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, raid, mount

I am switching to Debian from Ubuntu and so far all is good, however, I can't get Debian to read one RIAD drives.  I have three physical drives setup, using Intel Matrix Manager, for a RAID5 volume and one RAID0 volume.

I can mount the RAID0 Volume, but not the RAID5.

The RIAD members are sda, sdb, and sdc.

```
root@box:/dev# blkid 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="Media" UUID="64ee8b83-0f4b-48a3-b8dd-a9ed6ea920db" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/sdc: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="cb6ecb7b-bd4c-4330-b960-afe68a2f1ab9" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sdd5: UUID="a9218c20-6442-4e20-b45e-ba7321e47f82" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume111: UUID="dc21361e-792d-4f7e-b6c0-3e2530ce6a8a" TYPE="ext4"
```

---

```
root@box:/media/data3# dmraid -ay -v
ERROR: device-mapper target type "raid45" is not in the kernel
RAID set "isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume10" was not activated
RAID set "isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume11" already active
INFO: Activating GROUP raid set "isw_hhjcbdhaa"
RAID set "isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume111" already active
INFO: Activating partition raid set "isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume111"
```

---

```
root@box:/media/data3# dmraid -l
asr     : Adaptec HostRAID ASR (0,1,10)
ddf1    : SNIA DDF1 (0,1,4,5,linear)
hpt37x  : Highpoint HPT37X (S,0,1,10,01)
hpt45x  : Highpoint HPT45X (S,0,1,10)
isw     : Intel Software RAID (0,1,5,01)
jmicron : JMicron ATARAID (S,0,1)
lsi     : LSI Logic MegaRAID (0,1,10)
nvidia  : NVidia RAID (S,0,1,10,5)
pdc     : Promise FastTrack (S,0,1,10)
sil     : Silicon Image(tm) Medley(tm) (0,1,10)
via     : VIA Software RAID (S,0,1,10)
dos     : DOS partitions on SW RAIDs
```

Is `Intel Software RAID (0,1,5,01)`  related to the error message `"raid45" is not in the kernel`?

---

```
root@box:/dev# cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# / was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=cb6ecb7b-bd4c-4330-b960-afe68a2f1ab9 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdd5 during installation
UUID=a9218c20-6442-4e20-b45e-ba7321e47f82 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

---

```
root@box:/dev# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1             895G  3.6G  846G   1% /
tmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  5.9G  244K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 5.9G  140K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
```

---

```
root@box:/dev# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00055b4c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1      118605   952686592   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2          118605      121602    24073217    5  Extended
/dev/sdd5          118605      121602    24073216   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sde: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00011a54

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1      121601   976760001   83  Linux

Disk /dev/dm-0: 152.2 GB, 152237113344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18508 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 393216 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00050b82

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/dm-0p1               1       18509   148668672   83  Linux

Disk /dev/dm-2: 152.2 GB, 152236720128 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18508 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 393216 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

The line `Disk /dev/dm-2 doesn't contain a valid partition table` is troubling.

---

```
root@box:/dev# cat /etc/mdadm.conf 
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume10 container=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80 member=0 UUID=a5588995:17b457eb:8caa08b8:f739be84
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume11 container=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80 member=1 UUID=efb7bdff:2e76c9c1:318d1af5:f1ede0b7
```

---

```
root@box:/dev# cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume10 container=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80 member=0 UUID=a5588995:17b457eb:8caa08b8:f739be84
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume11 container=164dbe64:399a6a56:77eecaf7:56be1b80 member=1 UUID=efb7bdff:2e76c9c1:318d1af5:f1ede0b7

# This file was auto-generated on Thu, 10 Jan 2013 23:59:43 -0500
# by mkconf 3.1.4-1+8efb9d1+squeeze1
```

I've tried removing the mdadm.conf files, thinking it was causing a conflict..

```
root@box:/dev# mv /etc/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm.conf.bak
root@box:/dev# mv /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf.bak
```

DM-0 can not be mounted

```
root@box:  mount -t ext4 /dev/dm-0 /media/data4/
mount: /dev/mapper/isw_hhjcbdhaa_Volume11 already mounted or /media/data4/ busy
```

while DM-1 can be

```
root@box:  mount -t ext4 /dev/dm-1 /media/data4/
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up installing Linux Mint and it works fine, if my understanding is correct the current Debian kernel doesn't support RAID45.